# Plugins stopped working in Chromium in Debian Testing

Tags: debian, plugins, kde, chromium

Short time ago plugins stopped working in chromium. Neither of kpartsplugin, mozplugger nor flashplayer-nonfree seem to work. Neither comes up in `chrome://plugins` page (only "Chromoting Viewer" does).

Was there recently any change that would require reconfiguration? And if, of what?

I have Debian Testing (Jessie) amd64, recently updated, with chromium 35.0.1916.114-2, flashplugin-nonfree 1:3.4, kpartsplugin 20120605-1 and mozplugger 1.14.5-2.

Comment: [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/726789/flash-files-swf-prompts-for-download-instead-of-opening) is probably the same problem, but is less detailed and does not have answer anyway.

Comment: I also tried adding `--enable-plugins` in `/etc/chrome/defaults` (as hinted [here](http://superuser.com/a/44901/208928)), but it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

chrome 35 dropped support for NPAPI which basically breaks all plugnis (except for a handful that have been written for the new api.h

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379425