# Chrome downloads swf over opening it

Tags: windows, google-chrome, swf

**I realise [this](https://superuser.com/questions/726789/flash-files-swf-prompts-for-download-instead-of-opening) exists, but it's for Ubuntu and useless to me. I don't have that file.**

With that out of the way... I'm having issues opening a .swf file in Chrome. It was opening fine last night (and has been for a week or two now), and today, it's suddenly downloading over and over instead of opening. I have not modified any settings in Chrome, modified the file, downloaded anything, or otherwise intentionally and/or knowingly did that'd cause it to stop opening. A virus scan of my computer (using Avast) revealed no issues. Clearing cache/cookies did nothing.

It's worth noting that this is a Chrome-only issue. I am able to open it in Internet Explorer (though I'd highly prefer not to!). Edge was useless since it can't even open SWFs.

If you need any information about the file or Chrome, feel free to ask. I'm not sure what would be useful because my knowledge of this kind of thing is subpar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome://plugins/

Check "Always allowed to run" in the "Adobe Flash Player" section

Comment: hi, if I try *chrome://plugins/* I get **invalid url/this site can´t be reached** response. I tried looking for it in *chrome://settings/* but in the flash section all there is is a toggle *Ask first (recommended)/Block sites from running Flash*, neither allows the flash file to run in the browser. Help, please