# Is it possible to run shock wave flash files on Chromebook

Tags: flash, flash-player, chromebook

I am looking to run swf files no a chromebook is it at all possible, and if so , how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done? What have you found out so far? :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with chrome OS, but I found the similar issue with you.
The following is the marked answer.
*"Chrome has a built in Flash Player called PepperFlash. Go To chrome://plugins/ and ensure that "Adobe Flash Player" is Enabled. You can also go to chrome://components/ to ensure that it is updated. If you still have problems go to "Your Root"\Users\"Your UserName"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\"Version Number"\ Then rename the pepflashplayer.dll to pepflashplayerX.dll."

The referred link is:
[How can I play an .swf file using Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/116352/how-can-i-play-an-swf-file-using-google-chrome)

Try to check if it would be helpful for you.

Comment: I'm afraid that information is not applicable to ChromeOS systems. (It's not even applicable to Windows anymore -- the answer you're quoting is several years old.)